# What is the proper way to delete a tree node

Tags: codenameone

import com.codename1.ui.tree.Tree;
import com.codename1.ui.tree.TreeModel;
Upon detecting a delete action from my tree ActionListener,
I delete the path on disk.
FileSystemStorage.getInstance().delete(node.getPath());

Then attempt to refresh the tree where there is one less element in the curr node.
tree.expandPath(true,(Object[]) (node.getNodeParent().getNodesOnPath()));

Can you please provide a working example of delete a single leaf (file) and then refresh the Node Parent

My approach does not work.
If I manually tap on the Node Parent twice, I see the file id no longer displayed as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once it's shown the tree won't refresh unless you refresh the whole thing. Only hidden nodes take events into account so if you fold and reopen it will update. In the case of deletion you can just use something specific to the file and remove the specific node components from their parents directly which is a bit of a hack.

Alternatively you can refresh the entire tree which is what we do for the GUI builder by setting a new instance of the model. In the GUI builder that's practical because the tree is always expanded. It might be a bit painful for your implementation.